# wp_mail() sends wrong From header

Tags: wp-mail

When using this code below with `wp_mail()` I always get in the header
wordpress@mydomainname.nl. And in Thunderbird in column Correspondents: Wordpress.
But I need: 'From: "Klantenservice"<' . $emailTo . '>'

In https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ and other pages I can not find a solution for this.

```
    $body  = __('Name:', 'Avada')." $user_name \n\n";
    $body .= __('Email:', 'Avada')." $user_email \n\n";
    $body .= __('Telefoon:', 'Avada')." $telephone \n\n";
    $body .= __('Betreft:', 'Avada')." $subject \n\n";
    $body .= __('Bericht:', 'Avada')."\n $message";

    $headers = 'From: "Klantenservice"<' . $emailTo . '>' . "\r\n";
    $emailTo = 'info@mydomainname.nl';
    //$mail = wp_mail($user_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $mail = wp_mail($emailTo, 'Contact verzoek', $body, '');
```

How can I get this correct?

**Here the solution add this in functions.php**:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_mail_from_name' );
function my_mail_from_name( $name )
{
return "My Name";
}
```

Comment: why do you set the from headerto the `$emailTo` value? what is the value at all (not sure it relevant but maybe)

Comment: You never pass `$headers` to function in the code you posted?

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer to keep the site format tidy. You can accept it as correct too, after a couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the `$emailto` variable after the place you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold. First, setting the `$emailTo` **after** the header value where that variable is used (so it's empty in the header).

Second, the `$header` value that is set is not used in the actual call to `wp_mail()`. Instead it passes an empty value. (It is set in the line before, but it is commented out, presumably for testing.)

Here's the problematic section:

```
$headers = 'From: "Klantenservice"<' . $emailTo . '>' . "\r\n";
$emailTo = 'info@mydomainname.nl';
//$mail = wp_mail($user_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
$mail = wp_mail($emailTo, 'Contact verzoek', $body, '');
```

Here's what it should be:

```
$emailTo = 'info@mydomainname.nl';
$headers = 'From: "Klantenservice"<' . $emailTo . '>' . "\r\n";
//$mail = wp_mail($user_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
$mail = wp_mail($emailTo, 'Contact verzoek', $body, $headers);
```